# TCL - index param on "image create" with multitiff wont do with Img 1.4.14

Tags: image, tcl, tiff

I'm currently using the Image Lib Img 1.4.14 which does anything I ever wanted from a graphics LIB :)

However, I encounter just one problem while using MultiTIFF images. It is no problem to display the first picture of that tiff, but whenever I want to access any following images in that tiff, I don't receive any usable response from it.

Just an example line like this produces no output:

```
image create photo imgTest -file $filename -index 1
```

while

```
image create photo imgTest -file $filename
```

always gives me the first image correctly.

I tried tons of different approaches in calling the subsequent pctures to no avail. Thus I still think that the Img Lib is totally capable of doing it, so the problem seems to be on my side. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Additionally tried:
several different calls to the loading line, like :

```
image create photo imgTest -file $filename -format [-index 2]
```

Comment: There is definitely a non-obvious trick to it.

Answer (score 2):

To pass options to the image format handler, you need to use the `-format` option. But that's the name of the format! Well yes, the first word of it is. The subsequent words are the options. (If you don't pass options, you can rely on auto-detection.) That means you need something like this:

```
image create photo imgTest -file $filename -format [list tiff -index 2]
```

I'm not 100% sure that the name of the format handler is right; `tiff` is a guess.

Comment: In this case `-format "tiff -index 2"` would have also worked. Options to format handlers tend to be very simple words.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does it! 
In my original post at the bottom you see, that I tried to go that way a little bit, but the documentation is really weak at this point and examples are none :)

Thanks very much! I would upvote your post, but do not have enough reputation points right now :)

Comment: It is something we ought to document for the built-in GIF handler. Technically the TIFF handler is an independent piece of software that could do it's own thing... even if it follows the core patterns.